# edge-sql.js how to set connectionString?

Tags: sql-server, node.js

```
var edge = require('edge');

var getProduct = edge.func('sql', function () {/*
    select * from Products 
    where ProductId = @myProductId
*/});

getProduct({ myProductId: 10 }, function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(result);
});
```

This Code works well but I feel uncomfortable with setting the ConnectionString as ENVIROMENT_VARIALBE!

```
set EDGE_SQL_CONNECTION_STRING=Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True
```

But I can´t find a different way to do this! Even on [GitHub](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#how-to-script-t-sql-in-a-nodejs-application) I can´t find another way on how to set ConnectionString! So I wonder is it even possible in OOB edge-sql.js to set the ConnectionString in Code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking at the SourceCode of edge-sql, I was able to find out how it works, I wonder why on GitHub it is described with an EnviromentVariable?

Anyway here is the Code to set the ConnectionString in node.js :-)

```
var edge = require('edge');

var params = {
    connectionString: "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ITSM_604;Integrated Security=True",
    source: "select top 1 last_name from account_contact"
};

var getContacts = edge.func('sql', params);

getContacts(null, function(error, result){
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Ok, guys. You want to connect to SQL Server (in my case 2005) with integrated security? Use connectionString: "Data source=<sqlserver>;Integrated security=true" replace <sqlserver> with the host of your sql server in my case it's some pc on the network.

Answer (score 3):

Evidently (https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/issues/65), you can do it inline too:

```
var mySelect = edge.func('sql', {
    source: function () {/*
        select * from Product
    */},
    connectionString: 'your connection string goes here'
});
```

I don't like the environmental variable technique either.